# Lag when filtering ArrayList and setting adapter for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, tfs

Hey I'm trying to filter my `ArrayList` with `SwitchCompat` and show filtered list in a `RecyclerView` and I'm using this code:

```
    cancelled = (SwitchCompat) inc.findViewById(R.id.cancelledSwitch);
    cancelledByAdmin = (SwitchCompat) inc.findViewById(R.id.cancelledByAdminSwitch);
    reserved = (SwitchCompat) inc.findViewById(R.id.reservedSwitch);
    pending = (SwitchCompat) inc.findViewById(R.id.pendingSwitch);
    deprecated = (SwitchCompat) inc.findViewById(R.id.deprecatedSwitch);
    deprecated.setOnCheckedChangeListener(filterswitch);
    cancelled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(filterswitch);
    pending.setOnCheckedChangeListener(filterswitch);
    cancelledByAdmin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(filterswitch);
    reserved.setOnCheckedChangeListener(filterswitch);

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener filterswitch = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        filter();
    }
};

public void filter() {
    ArrayList<ReservedTimesModel> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ReservedTimesModel reservedTimesModel : arrayList) {
        switch (reservedTimesModel.res_status) {
            case "CanceledByAdmin":
                if (cancelledByAdmin.isChecked()) {
                    filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
                }
                break;
            case "Canceled":
                if (cancelled.isChecked()) {
                    filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
                }
                break;
            case "Pending":
                if (pending.isChecked()) {
                    filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
                }
                break;
            case "Deprecated":
                if (pending.isChecked()) {
                    filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (reserved.isChecked()) {
                    filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
                }
        }
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ReservedTimesAdapter(filtered, ReservedTimesActivity.this));
}
```

ReservedTimesAdapter:

```
public class ReservedTimesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReservedTimesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<ReservedTimesModel> arrayList;
Context context;
StyleSpan bold = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

public ReservedTimesAdapter(ArrayList<ReservedTimesModel> arrayList, Activity context) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    AppCompatButton cancel;
    TextView node_titletxt, timetxt, datetxt, statustxt, doctxt;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        cancel = (AppCompatButton) v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_reserve);
        statustxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reserved_status);
        datetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reserved_date);
        timetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reserved_time);
        node_titletxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.node_title);
        doctxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reserved_doctor);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.reserved_times_list_layout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (arrayList.get(position).cancelable) {
        if (arrayList.get(position).res_status.equals("Reserved")) {
            holder.cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    click(position);
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }else{
        holder.cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    SpannableStringBuilder date = new SpannableStringBuilder("تاریخ: " + convert_num(arrayList.get(position).year + "/" + arrayList.get(position).month + "/" + arrayList.get(position).day));
    date.setSpan(bold,0,6, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    holder.datetxt.setText(date);
    String title;
    if (arrayList.get(position).typename.equals("Hospital")) {
        title = "بیمارستان";
    } else {
        title = "کلینیک";
    }

    SpannableStringBuilder doc = new SpannableStringBuilder("دکتر: " + arrayList.get(position).doc);
    doc.setSpan(bold, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    holder.doctxt.setText(doc);

    SpannableStringBuilder node_title = new SpannableStringBuilder(title + " " + arrayList.get(position).node_title);
    node_title.setSpan(bold, 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    holder.node_titletxt.setText(node_title);

    SpannableStringBuilder time = new SpannableStringBuilder("زمان: " + convert_num(arrayList.get(position).ft_to_time.substring(0, 5) + " - " + arrayList.get(position).ft_of_time.substring(0, 5)));
    time.setSpan(bold, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    holder.timetxt.setText(time);

    String status;
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_shape);
    switch (arrayList.get(position).res_status) {
        case "CanceledByAdmin":
            status = context.getString(R.string.cancelled_by_admin);
            drawable.setColorFilter(0xFFFC635D, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
            break;
        case "Canceled":
            status = context.getString(R.string.cancelled);
            drawable.setColorFilter(0xFFEE903D, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
            break;
        case "Pending":
            status = context.getString(R.string.pending);
            drawable.setColorFilter(0xFFd25913, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
            break;
        case "Deprecated":
            status = context.getString(R.string.deprecated);
            drawable.setColorFilter(0xFF757575, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
            break;
        default:
            status = context.getString(R.string.reserved);
            drawable.setColorFilter(0xFF3BA757, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
    }
    holder.statustxt.setBackground(drawable);
    holder.statustxt.setText(status);
}

public String convert_num(String string) {
    string = string.replace("0", "۰").replace("1", "۱").replace("2", "۲").replace("3", "۳").replace("4", "۴").replace("5", "۵").replace("6", "۶").replace("7", "۷").replace("8", "۸").replace("9", "۹");
    return string;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public void click(final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("بله", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final Trans trans = new Trans();
            trans.getPaymentMode(context, new AsyncResponse<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.replace("\"", "").equals("Direct")) {
                        trans.cancelReserve(context, new AsyncResponse<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                if (response.equals("true")) {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                    alertDialogBuilder1.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                                    alertDialogBuilder1.setPositiveButton("ادامه", null);
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog1 = alertDialogBuilder1.create();
                                    alertDialog1.show();
                                    alertDialog1.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(18);
                                    TextView title = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.title);
                                    title.setText("توجه!");
                                    TextView tet = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.text);
                                    tet.setText("رزرو با موفقیت لغو شد.");
                                    arrayList.get(position).res_status = "Canceled";
                                    synchronized (this) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                                            notifyItemChanged(i);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                    alertDialogBuilder1.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                                    alertDialogBuilder1.setPositiveButton("ادامه", null);
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog1 = alertDialogBuilder1.create();
                                    alertDialog1.show();
                                    alertDialog1.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(18);
                                    TextView title = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.title);
                                    title.setText("خطا!");
                                    TextView tet = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.text);
                                    tet.setText("عملیات لغو رزرو وقت موفقیت‌آمیز نبود. لطفا مجدداً تکرار فرمایید.");
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(String error) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                alertDialogBuilder1.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                                alertDialogBuilder1.setPositiveButton("ادامه", null);
                                AlertDialog alertDialog1 = alertDialogBuilder1.create();
                                alertDialog1.show();
                                alertDialog1.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(18);
                                TextView title = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.title);
                                title.setText("خطا!");
                                TextView tet = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.text);
                                tet.setText("عملیات لغو رزرو وقت موفقیت‌آمیز نبود. لطفا مجدداً تکرار فرمایید.");
                            }
                        }, arrayList.get(position).ft_id, arrayList.get(position).res_id);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CreditCardActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ft_id", arrayList.get(position).ft_id);
                        intent.putExtra("res_id", arrayList.get(position).res_id);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(String error) {

                }
            }, arrayList.get(position).node_id);
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("خیر", null);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(18);
    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextSize(18);
    TextView title = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText("تایید لغو رزرو");
    TextView tet = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

My `arrayList`s size is 18 but when I'm clicking on one of the `SwitchCompat`s it lags about 1sec. Why is this happening?

Comment: did you try to profile your app? see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html)

Comment: imho the bottelneck is ``Html.fromHtml`` inside `onBindViewHolder`, use `Spannable#setSpan` instead, did you profile your app? have you seen a link i posted above?

Comment: yeah i checked that but it's difficult to understand @pskink

Comment: what is difficult to understand? did you try to remove `fromHtml`?

Comment: so **profile** your app and use `traceview`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to `setAdapter` every time your data changes.
you create an adapter once (in your activity `onCreate()` ) and every time your data changes set data to adapter again and call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

add this method to `ReservedTimesAdapter` class

```
 public void setList( ArrayList<ReservedTimesModel> arrayList)
    {
      this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
```

then define a `ReservedTimesAdapter` object and add `setAdapter` code to your activity `onCreate()` class.like this:

```
 ReservedTimesAdapter myAdapter=  new ReservedTimesAdapter(filtered, ReservedTimesActivity.this);

 recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

and change the `filter` method as below :

```
public void filter() {
    ArrayList<ReservedTimesModel> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ReservedTimesModel reservedTimesModel : arrayList) {
    switch (reservedTimesModel.res_status) {
        case "CanceledByAdmin":
            if (cancelledByAdmin.isChecked()) {
                filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
            }
            break;
        case "Canceled":
            if (cancelled.isChecked()) {
                filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
            }
            break;
        case "Pending":
            if (pending.isChecked()) {
                filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
            }
            break;
        case "Deprecated":
            if (pending.isChecked()) {
                filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (reserved.isChecked()) {
                filtered.add(reservedTimesModel);
            }
      }
  }
  myAdapter.setList(filtered);
  myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that both `new ReservedTimesAdapter()` and `recyclerView.setAdapter()` are time-consuming tasks